# How to find N consecutive numbers are equal in array?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a numpy.ndarray that has values -1 or 1. The array is quite long, but I will post a little sample.

```
array([ 1, -1,  1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1,  1, -1,
    1,  1,  1], dtype=int8)
```

The array continues till about index 200. I would like to find the location where there are N consecutive values equal to either 1 or -1. So in the example above it should return index 11, 12, 13 if N was equal to 8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `.cumsum` to implement a sliding window:

```
a = np.array([ 1, -1,  1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1,  1, -1,
    1,  1,  1], dtype=np.int8) 
N = 8

A = a.cumsum()
A[N:] -= A[:-N]
(np.abs(A)==N).nonzero()[0]
# array([11, 12, 13])
```

Answer (score 4):

I would like to share my naive solution using lists

let `arr = [1,1,-1,-1,...]`

```
index = []
myList = list(arr)
for i in range(m-n): # m is length of array
    if myList[i:i+n].count(1)==n or myList[i:i+n].count(-1)==n:
        index.append(i)
```

`index[]` now holds all indices which satisfy your condition

Comment: Since `m` is already length of the array, there is no meaning of `len(m)`. It will give an error.

Comment: Thank you @DhavalTaunk

Answer (score 2):

Here's one with [`np.convolve`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html) -

```
np.flatnonzero(np.convolve(np.diff(a)==0, [1]*(N-1))==(N-1))+1
```

Sample run -

```
In [146]: N = 8

In [147]: np.flatnonzero(np.convolve(np.diff(a)==0, [1]*(N-1))==(N-1))+1
Out[147]: array([11, 12, 13])
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged `pandas`:

```
s = pd.Series(a)

N = 8
np.where(s.diff().eq(0).rolling(N-1).sum()==N-1)
```

Output:

```
(array([11, 12, 13]),)
```